# Cause of undefined rxjs subscription source

Tags: angular, rxjs, lifecycle

In a large Angular 8 application I have this intermittent failure:

```
ERROR TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
    at subscribeTo (subscribeTo.js:27)
    at subscribeToResult (subscribeToResult.js:11)
    at SwitchMapSubscriber._innerSub (switchMap.js:46)
    at SwitchMapSubscriber._next (switchMap.js:36)
    at SwitchMapSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
    at WithLatestFromSubscriber._next (withLatestFrom.js:57)
    at WithLatestFromSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
    at WithLatestFromSubscriber._next (withLatestFrom.js:57)
    at WithLatestFromSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
    at FilterSubscriber._next (filter.js:33)
```

I have not been able to reliably reproduce the error, so I am engaged in thinking through the issue. I would like to get a sanity check on my reasoning so far:

The basic subscription might be something like this...

```
this.store.pipe(
      select(getAllStatus),
      takeUntil(this.isDestroyed),
      map(loading)
    ).subscribe(isLoading => . . .
```

where `getAllStatus` is an imported selector created by `createSelector`.
The above error could **not** come from such a statement because, while `isLoading` might certainly be `undefined`, the source Observable itself--the output of the pipe--could never be undefined.

So then we get a more interesting case. (Note, this is just a random example from my codebase; it is **not** the line causing the error.)

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.authorizedChecker.isAuthorized$.subscribe(. . .
}
```

The success of the subscription depends on when `authorizedChecker` and its `isAuthorized$` property are both initialized.
Because the error is complaining about the subscription attempt, that says `authorizedChecker` is certainly defined. But if its `isAuthorized$` is not yet defined, that could cause the given error.

Now, `authorizedChecker` is defined in the constructor. In this particular case it is an explicit object creation...

```
constructor(
    private store: Store<NgrxStateAtom>
  ) {
    this.authorizedChecker = new AuthorizedChecker(this.store);
  }
```

but there are other uses where it is created by dependency injection, for example:

```
constructor(
    public layoutFacade: LayoutFacadeService
  ) {
```

In either case, we know that sub-components's constructor will complete its work before yielding the object; the AuthorizedChecker constructor begins with this...

```
constructor(private store: Store<NgrxStateAtom>) {
    this.isAuthorized$ =
      this.store.select(allPerms).pipe(. . .
```

Because `isAuthorized$` is defined in the constructor, then the call I started with (`this.authorizedChecker.isAuthorized$.subscribe`) should **never** fail with the given error.

But that got me thinking: what if `isAuthorized$` is defined in an `ngOnInit` ? The docs on [lifecycle hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks) do not really go into much detail. How does the sub-components `ngOnInit` relate to the current component's `ngOnInit` where the `subscribe` is being attempted? There seems no guarantee of the ordering, so this could certainly cause the error in question. (Seems like it is an unsafe practice to define Observables in an `ngOnInit`; is that the case?)

A variation of this is in the realm of a template, where one might use an expression like `{{ isAuthorized$ | async }}`). I have not found details about how the async pipe creates its implicit subscription but that seems susceptible to the same circumstances and thus could also be the source of error.

Questions: Am I looking in the right direction? Are there other scenarios that might cause this error?

Comment: Have you ever used this? https://github.com/cartant/rxjs-spy. It might help with a complex intermittent problem like yours.

Comment: This error happens when you return `undefined` from a projection function that expect an Observable. It's the common mistake when using `catchError`, `mergeMap` or `switchMap`. Your stacktrace says it comes from `switchMap` which is followed by `withLatestFrom` so I'd search the project for any usage of `withLatestFrom` because that's not a very common operator. The bad thing is that this error might be thrown from a 3rd part code. `async` pipe wouldn't cause this error because with `undefined` it just unsubscribes from the previous Observable and does nothing.

Comment: @Tom Thanks; that rxjs-spy looks intriguing; will give it a whirl.

Comment: @martin You were correct: just had to find where I had a `switchMap` and a `withLatestFrom`... and I found that I had neglected to return a value on one branch of a conditional. Thanks!